# How to use variable expansion in shell script

Tags: bash, sed, brace-expansion

I have a script that looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#
for i in `seq -w 22 35`
do
  cd /folder/d"$i"
  generate_XDS.INP d"$i"_001.img.bz2 #makes a text file "XDS.INP" 
  u=`grep UNIT_CELL_CONSTANTS /folder/d${i-1}/CORRECT.LP | tail -n 1` #get info from previous run
#u is supposed to be something like: UNIT_CELL_CONSTANTS=    79.08    79.08    37.02  90.000  90.000  90.000
  sed -e "s:NAME_TEMPLATE_OF_DATA_FRAMES=./d${i}_001.img.bz2:NAME_TEMPLATE_OF_DATA_FRAMES=./d${i}_???.img.bz2:" -e 's:DATA_RANGE=:DATA_RANGE=1 100:' -e 's:SPOT_RANGE=:SPOT_RANGE=1 100:' -e 's:SPACE_GROUP_NUMBER=0:SPACE_GROUP_NUMBER=96:' -e "s:UNIT_CELL_CONSTANTS= 70 80 90 90 90 90:${u}:" XDS.INP > a #Change a few lines in input so that the job can run. 
  mv a XDS.INP
done
```

The problem is the "u=line". I used to have something like this, without the u=line and the two last substitute commands in the sed line, and it worked. Now u appears empty and the sed command does not end successfully. How can I fix this?
I know this has something to do with the {brace} expansion. But I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to isolate the problem further; using `set -x` to log each individual command tends to be helpful. If `i=22; echo ${i-1}` does what you expect (it'll print `22` -- whether that's what you expect is something your question doesn't address), then your thoughts on where the problem is may be misplaced.

Comment: Have you tried anything to debug this? `echo` the value of `/folder/d${i-1}/CORRECT.LP` and make sure it exists would be the first thing I would try, then make sure it has the value that `grep` is looking for. Also worth mentioning bash has built in sequences: `for i in {22..35}; do`

Comment: (...the real question, though, is **what do you expect?** -- `${i-1}` expands `$i`, with `1` as a default value if `i` is unset; we're not mind readers, and can't tell if that's the behavior you wanted).

Comment: Also copy/paste your script in https://www.shellcheck.net for fixing syntax issues, fix stuff until it says _No issues detected_

Comment: BTW, `seq` is a nonstandard external command -- if you want to work everywhere bash is available, consider using a [C-style `for` loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's the actual problem here, but `${i-1}` will not evaluate an arithmetical expression, as you likely intended.

Either use `$(( i - 1 ))`, which will work in most shells (like bash, dash, etc.) and is the preferred syntax for arithmetical expressions or use `$[ i - 1 ]`, which will work in bash, but not in some other shells. Also, the latter syntax is discouraged, as pointed out by Charles Duffy's comment.

Comment: `$(( i - 1 ))` is preferred in bash also. `$[ i - 1 ]` is legacy syntax for compatibility with pre-POSIX Bourne -- but with POSIX sh having come out in the early 90s, pre-POSIX Bourne isn't exactly something one needs compatibility with in modern times.

Comment: Sure, but it's likely not intended here.

Comment: It's an educated guess, due to the keyword "previous" in the comment. So do you suggest I delete the answer?

Comment: Since it's here, and *is* quite likely correct, might as well keep it. Mentioning the legacy Bourne syntax is actually my bigger beef -- better that that be lost and forgotten to time.

Comment: Not at all, just pointing out you're making an assumption. Probably a correct one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy improved the second paragraph with the help of your comment regarding the first syntax being preferred even in bash.

Comment: Don't use `$[ i - 1 ]` at all. It was deprecated decades ago (literally; you can see references to its being deprecated in commits from 1996), and hasn't even been mentioned in the documentation for quite some time.